# Do scriptures talk about performing samskaras for non Hindus?

Tags: other-religions, samskara

I have seen Americans who didn't seem to be Hare Krishnas get Hindu priests to perform sacraments for the success of their business.  Are Hindu priests allowed to do this according to scriptures?

Comment: sacraments is a Christian term. What do you mean?

Comment: it means- Initiation, Samsakaras.. @SwamiVishwananda but in the context OP probably meant doing rituals/puja.

Comment: Are u asking whether Hindu priests can do Pujas for the non-Hindus? @@SK

Comment: rituals,puja,yagnas,japam etc.

Comment: Dharma is for the entire humanity. The only reason why a non-Hindu can be denied puja is given in Gita 18.67 or in this shloka: 'These teachings are not to be imparted to persons who are wicked, haughty, barbarous, foul in conduct, hypocritical, given to sensuous indulgences, interested exclusively in their worldly concerns, who are without devotion to Me or who persecute My devotees.' Srimad Bhagavata Purana III.32.39-40...

Answer (score 3):

The Brahmins who officiate as priests for the Sudras are condemned in the scriptures..

See the following verses from the Manu Smriti:

> 11.42. Those who, obtaining wealth from Sudras, (and using that) offer an Agnihotra, are priests officiating for Sudras, (and hence) censured
>   among those who recite the Veda.
>
> 11.43. Treading with his foot on the heads of those fools who worship a fire (kindled at the expense) of a Sudra, the giver (of the wealth)
>   shall always pass over his miseries (in the next world).

Similar things are said in other scriptures as well. Like the Vashishta Dharma Sutras 15.21 says:

> A man who has divulged the Veda or **officiated at a Sudra’s
>   sacrifice,** and those who have fallen from the rank of the highest
>   class––for them the rite of overturning the water pot should be
>   performed.  slave, a son from a wife of a lower caste, or a relative
>   of a lower class lacking good qualities should fetch a broken pot from
>   a heap of unusable pots; spread on the ground some Darbha grass or
>   Lohita grass with their tips cut off; and overturn the pot filled with
>   water with his left foot for that person. 13 And his relatives, their
>   hair dishevelled, should touch the man who overturned the pot. They
>   may then return home as they wish, turning their left side towards
>   that place

Now, assuming the American is not a Hindu living as that country's citizen, such an act will obviously not be allowed.. Because, the American won't be included in the 4-class Hindu Varna system.

So, when officiating for the Sudra is condemned what to say about officiating for one who does not even belong to the Varna-system?

Comment: it makes me cringe to see "sudra,sudra,sudra.....".  At any rate my question was only about non-Hindus, who I guess would not have a caste. Now at the Srirangam temple, a Muslim (tulukka nachiyar) has a sanctum, so I guess non-Hindus can be worshiped. @rickross

Comment: I asked in the spirit of inclusion and you answered in the spirit of exclusion.  due to internet, the prayer to vishnu from narayaneeyam to cure disease has spread to non Hindus @rickross

Comment: **Everyone can be included in Hinduism..** irrespective of anything.. the Tantras shows us the way... a prime example would be Sir John Woodruffe.. But there is no scope for such inclusions in the Vedic religion.. "
it makes me cringe to see" -- I can not really help.. we have to answer with quotes from scriptures and they will have such verses..all scriptures have them..  " would not have a caste." Yes they will be regarded as Varna Sankaras or  Mlecchas.. so, priests officiating for them for money won't be allowed.. @SK

Comment: "I asked in the spirit of inclusion and you answered in the spirit of exclusion" Then you did not make that clear.. that's why i did ask for clarification under ur Q before posting the answer.. If ur Q is "Is there a way by which a desirous non Hindu can be part of Hinduism?" then the answer will be Yes.. He can belong to Hinduism by the power of Tantrik Diksha Samskara.. @SK But ur current Q is "Can a Hindu priest perform rituals for some Non Hindus for money" Then No as per scriptures..

Comment: A hindu can walk into a christian church, listen to the service and partake of the wine and holy wafer.  There is no conversion, nothing - he briefly receives Christian blessing and walks out.  I was asking can something similar be done within Hinduism. @rickross

Comment: Whether that is allowed for the Christians to do is for them to answer.. If we go by the Hindu scriptures, then scriptures won't speak highly of such priests who do so.. Anything else i say will be my personal opinion.. @SK "I was asking can something similar be done within Hinduism" --Can be done means of course we see it being done..but if u ask "Do scriptures approve ?" then possibly no as my answer shows..

Comment: You don't know if it is obviously not allowed. The question does not ask about Sudras. It asks for foreigners. You posted one answer for another question. If you have anything about foreigners, then post it. User's opinions don't count here. The main question what to do when there is a foreigner and you missed it completely.

Comment: I have explained enough in the answer itself as to why it won't be allowed..OP is asking whether Hindu priests are allowed to do archanas for foreigners who will be called the Mlecchas in the scriptures..So the answer is quite obvious.. @Sarvabhouma

Comment: Hinduism is anti foreigner. The OP is asking performing poojas, yajnas for the well being of them. It is for all the world. Hindus wish for the welfare of all the world including animals. Sudras are not the same as Mlechhas and foreigners. If there is a verse for foreigners, then quote it. Currently it is only speculation.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma It is not a speculation.. here the archans are done for money.. and they are not doing it for the benefit of all beings..so two situations are distinct... Mlecchas who do not even belong to the system will be considered worst than the Sudras as the latter belong to the system and they are governed by the rules of it.. Moreover  one my own post shows that doing Pujas in Mleccha Deshas are condemned..

Comment: @rickross in today's world almost every temple priest does puja/japa/homa for shudras, that includes some of the most cultured Shankaracharya mutts. Does this mean they don't know our don't follow the scriptures? Must be some misinterpretation here? Let's say priests perform puja for the welfare of the Shudra and Shudra gives Dhakshina; that's also same?

Comment: Sir but Puranik Pujas can be performed by and to Sudras right? Sudras also celebrate ganesh Chaturthi Janmastami Ram Navami,make a diety,offer flowers,lit Diya and Chant Mantras(Puranic) ..CHinna Jiyar Swami himself built temples for Dalits and made them Priests.

Comment: Sudras can do almost everything that a higher caste man is allowed to do. In Hinduism there are two paths Vedic and Tantric. While there are some caste based prohibitions on the Sudras in the Vedic way the Tantric path is open to all. Sudras can be initiated in Tantras and they are qualified to practice the religion, perform Pujas and everything else. So, it's not a problem at all @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: Buautiful sir! So they can bring an Idol of Krishna and lit Diyas,offer flowers,Naivedya,Sing Krishnastakam(Puranic) and read Bhagavatam right?

Comment: Yes, if you are initiated by a Guru you are qualified to do all that and much more @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: Super sir! Thanks a lot! Jai Sri Krishna!

Comment: Sir one more thing-Sudras were allowed into temples. I saw when Preists did Harathi to Lord Venkateshwara(Vishnu) they came down and blessed everyone,offered Tirtha,Prasada  and showed Harathi and also put the feet of Lord (Satagopam) on everyone without seeing Caste-That is permitted right? 
And we know when Thirupan Alvar was not allowed Lord himself asked Bramhana to take him inside temple..on his head....

Comment: Yes allowed that is why the temple priests offered them the blessings @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: Thankyou sir  